# Receive RTP stream with gstreamer

Tags: python, linux, opencv, gstreamer, rtp

I'm trying to stream from a linux-based microcontroller, using gstreamer, to a python script. This is to workaround some firmware issues on the microcontroller where it cannot open the camera directly with opencv/python.

The launch output command looks like this for gstreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0  ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! avenc_mpeg4 bitrate=4000000 ! rtpmp4vpay config-interval=1 ! udpsink host="$1" port=5004
```

My question is, what would the "receive" command look like? Currently it's using this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5004 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)MP4" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! glimagesink
```

But that throws the error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link udpsrc0 to rtpmp4vdepay0
```

It seems like I'm missing something....there's not much documentation on how to properly write the receive scripts. Ultimately, I'd be putting into python with something like:

```
cap_receive = cv2.VideoCapture('gstreamer receive command script goes here' , cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Any insights greatly appreciated, TIA!

Comment: In addition to @Florian Zwoch's answer, I would like to remind you that you need to end your pipeline with `appsink` in order to use with `cv2.VideoCapture`. So it will look something like `udpsrc port=5004 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the output of `gst-inspect-1.0 rtpmp4vdepay` you will notice the following caps for the sink pad:

```
  SINK template: 'sink'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      application/x-rtp
                  media: video
             clock-rate: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
          encoding-name: MP4V-ES
```

You will notice that the `encoding-name` is actually `MP4V-ES`.

On top of that - you cannot connect the RTP depacketizer directly to an image sink. You will have to parse, decode and color convert before that. Perhaps a `decodebin` can help you here if you want want to build the pipeline by hand..

Comment: Hello, thank you for this! 

I tried this solution as well as adding the decodebin & videoconvert from @alper 's comment. 

I essentially tried different variations of: `udpsrc port=5004 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink'` while it runs without any errors, opencv consistently fails to open the videocapture (`cap_receive.isOpened()` is false) is there any place with documentation on all the pipeline tags?

Comment: Additionally, that 'receive' script works totally fine with glimagesink. The video feed displays fine...so it feels close....

`udpsrc port=5004 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! glimagesink`

Comment: Realized after some continued debugging that actually my version of opencv-python does not have gstreamer support enabled, which is a separate problem--so thank you all and closing this thread! The gstreamer receive part of it seems to be solved :)